# Testing of methods which are written in seeds.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have written a ruby class with some methods in seeds.rb file
which is responsible for uploading content in different tables in database  .
Now I have written some  tests for methods in that class ..
But after running my test i am getting  error like
-------------------error-------------------
 Uncaught exception: uninitialized constant "ModelName"

```
---------------test file -----------------

    require_relative "../../db/seeds"
    require "minitest_helper"
    it "should  create a object" do
        object = class_name.new('file_name.csv')
        object1 = object.find_and_create_object('Region', :name => 'region_name')
        object1.id.wont_be_nil
    end
--------------------seeds.rb file ---------------
  module Gen
    def find_or_create_object(model_name, attributes)
     target_model = model_name.classify.constantize
     target_model.where(attributes).first_or_create
    end
  end
  class class_name
    include Gen 
    def create_object
         find_or_create_object('modelname',{value_hash})
    end
  end
but if i am running db:seed then everything is working ...(no error) ---
```

Comment: put your logic in a dedicated folder in lib

Comment: `class_name` is not a valid class name in Ruby. It should start with an uppercase letter.